# Communicating with a windows executables commandline gui via python

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7, command-line, subprocess

I am trying to run a Windows executable using python 2.7.

I can spawn a subprocess via the module.

The exe file runs in a cmd window normally and outputs a basic GUI.

E.g.

- Enter name: (waits on name)
- Enter age: (waits on age)

Do calculations...

Program terminates.

I would like my python script to pass "name" and "age" to the executable when appropriate.

Is it possible to do this on Windows?

I have heard of pexpect, but this does not work on Windows.

Comment: There's no such thing as *command line gui* as gui stands for **Graphical User Interface** and command line is not graphical.

Comment: Command Line interface.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try to pass the input via subprocess' stdin:

```
import os
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

p = Popen("some_program.exe", stdin=PIPE)
p.communicate(os.linesep.join(["name", "age"]))
```